# Catch Keyboard Interrupt in program that is waiting on an Event

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, windows-7, python-3.x

The following program hangs the terminal such that it ignores `Ctrl+C`. This is rather annoying since I have to restart the terminal every time one of the threads hang.

Is there any way to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` while waiting on an event?

```
import threading
def main():
    finished_event = threading.Event()
    startThread(finished_event)
    finished_event.wait()#I want to stop the program here
    print('done!')
def startThread(evt):
    """Start a thread that will trigger evt when it is done"""
    #evt.set()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** On the current Python 3 `finished_event.wait()` works on my Ubuntu machine (starting with Python 3.2). You don't need to specify the `timeout` parameter, to interrupt it using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. You need to pass the `timeout` parameter on CPython 2.

Here's a complete code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading

def f(event):
    while True:
        pass
    # never reached, otherwise event.set() would be here

event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=f, args=[event], daemon=True).start()
try:
    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')
    event.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('got Ctrl+C')
```

There could be [bugs](https://bugs.python.org/issue8844) related to [Ctrl+C](https://bugs.python.org/issue23237). Test whether it works in your environment.

---

<sup>Old polling answer:</sup>

You could try to allow the interpreter to run the main thread:

```
while not finished_event.wait(.1): # timeout in seconds
    pass
```

If you just want to wait until the child thread is done:

```
while thread.is_alive():
    thread.join(.1)
```

Comment: I don't know. Does it work with polling? Why polling is bad? You could test whether `time.sleep(large_timeout)` is interrupted by `Ctrl+C`. It might react to `Ctrl+C` sooner though it is still polling. The code that should react on `finished_event.set()` should be put into yet another thread in this case if you need responsiveness to the event.

Comment: Well, I tend to avoid polling even when I don't really need responsiveness, but I guess this is the only solution.

Comment: Word of warning for the `while True: pass`: this will get one of your CPU cores to 100%. If you really need to use this solution, better to throw a `time.sleep(0.1)` before the `pass`, to keep consumption to the minimum.

Comment: @NicoVillanueva: `while True: pass` is just a place holder for your real code that does some meaningful work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid polling, you can use the `pause()` function of the [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.pause) module instead of `finished_event.wait()`. `signal.pause()` is a blocking function and gets unblocked when a signal is received by the process. In this case, when ^C is pressed, SIGINT signal unblocks the function. Note that the function does not work on Windows according to the documentation. I've tried it on Linux and it worked for me.

I came across this solution in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3102501/2557681).

Comment: A little late but thanks for a non-polling answer :)

Comment: I think you can edit your answer to be more simple and direct, but you solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also patch the Event.wait() function in the following manner:

```
def InterruptableEvent():
    e = threading.Event()

    def patched_wait():
        while not e.is_set():
            e._wait(3)

    e._wait = e.wait
    e.wait = patched_wait
    return e


>>> event = InterruptableEvent()
>>> try:
...     event.wait()
... except KeyboardInterrupt:
...     print "Received KeyboardInterrupt"
... 
^CReceived KeyboardInterrupt
```

This works because wait() with a timeout argument *will* raise a KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: Ah but this is still polling like the accepted answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Pete's answer, but with subclassing and using the actual `Event.wait` method, just with smaller timeouts to allow handling of `KeyboardInterrupt`s and such in between:

```py
class InterruptableEvent(threading.Event):
    def wait(self, timeout=None):
        wait = super().wait  # get once, use often
        if timeout is None:            
            while not wait(0.01):  pass
        else:
            wait(timeout)
```