# multiprocessing.Event.wait hangs when interrupted by a signal

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I use the following code to handle the SIGINT event. The code sets a multiprocessing.event to "wakeup" the main thread which is waiting.

```
import multiprocessing
import signal

class Class1(object):
    _stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    @staticmethod
    def interrupt():
        Class1._stop_event.set()

    def wait(self):
        print("Waiting for _stop_event")
        if Class1._stop_event.wait(5):
            print("_stop_event set.")
        else:
            print("Timed out.")

def stop(signum, frame):
    print("Received SIG")
    Class1.interrupt()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)

c = Class1()
c.wait()
```

Without any signal, the wait method times out after 10 seconds and the process exits with the following output as expected:

```
Waiting for _stop_event
Timed out.
```

When sending the SIGINT signals, the signal gets handled but the event.wait method does not return, neither immediately nor after the timeout. The process *never* exits. The output is:

```
Waiting for _stop_event
^CReceived SIG
```

I can continue to send SIGINTs. The process won't exit and the output is:

```
Waiting for _stop_event
^CReceived SIG
^CReceived SIG
^CReceived SIG
^CReceived SIG
....
```

Everything works as expected if I replace the Class1.wait method with a check for event.is_set:

```
def wait(self):
    print("Waiting for _stop_event")
    while True:
        if Class1._stop_event.is_set():
            print("_stop_event set.")
            break
```

The process exits and the output is:

```
Waiting for _stop_event
^CReceived SIG
_stop_event set.
```

How to make event.wait return once the event was set?
What is the reason that the wait method doesn't even timeout anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You guys are going to like this one.  Use `threading.Event`, not `multiprocessing.Event`.  Then when you press `^C` the signal handler is called just like it should!

### source

```
import threading
import signal

class Class1(object):
    _stop_event = threading.Event()

    @staticmethod
    def interrupt():
        Class1._stop_event.set()

    def wait(self):
        print("Waiting for _stop_event")
        if Class1._stop_event.wait(5):
            print("_stop_event set.")
        else:
            print("Timed out.")

def stop(signum, frame):
    print("Received SIG")
    Class1.interrupt()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)

c = Class1()
c.wait()
```

### output

```
Waiting for _stop_event
^CReceived SIG
_stop_event set.
```

Comment: Nice! Works like a charm for me on Linux. Does not set the event on "simulated" SIGINT on Windows though.

Answer (score 7):

Signals are only handled on the main thread. If the main thread is blocked in a system call, that system call will raise an InterruptedError.

From the Python docs:

> they [signals] can only occur between the “atomic” instructions of the Python
>   interpreter

A time.sleep, for example, would raise an InterruptedError. It seems like the event.wait method does not deal with this scenario correctly. It does not raise an InterruptedError but simply starts to hang. This looks like a bug in Python to me?

---

UPDATE:

I narrowed this down to a deadlock in multiprocessing.Event. If the main thread is waiting for an event and at the same time, a signal sets that event on the interrupted main thread, then the multiprocessing.event.set() and multiprocessing.event.wait() methods deadlock each other.

Also, the behavior is heavily platform dependent. E.g. a time.sleep() would raise an InterruptedError on Windows but simply return on Linux.

---

A really clunky workaround is to keep the main thread free for processing signals.

```
import multiprocessing
import signal
import threading
import time


class Class1(object):
    _stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    @staticmethod
    def interrupt():
        Class1._stop_event.set()

    def wait_timeout(self):
        print("Waiting for _stop_event")
        if Class1._stop_event.wait(30):
            print("_stop_event set.")
        else:
            print("Timeout")


def stop(signum, frame):
    print("Received SIG")
    Class1.interrupt()
    exit_event.set()


def run():
    c = Class1()
    c.wait_timeout()

t = threading.Thread(target=run)
t.daemon = False
t.start()

exit_event = multiprocessing.Event()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)

while not exit_event.is_set():
    # Keep a main thread around to handle the signal and
    # that thread must not be in a event.wait()!
    try:
        time.sleep(500)
    except InterruptedError:
        # We were interrupted by the incoming signal.
        # Let the signal handler stop the process gracefully.
        pass
```

This is ugly as fuck. Someone please provide a more elegant solution....

Comment: For me what solve the issue was using `multiprocessing.Event` and that `while not exit_event.is_set()` instead of using `exit_event.wait()`. Thanks!

Comment: You can also delegate `exit_event.set()` to another thread instead of calling it and creating a deadlock. Basically, the signal callback becomes: `Thread(target=exit_event.set).start()`

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively use the `pause()` function of the [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.pause) module instead of `Event().wait()`. `signal.pause()` sleeps until a signal is received by the process. In this case, when SIGINT is received, the `signal.pause()` exits, returning nothing. Note that the function does not work on Windows according to the documentation. I've tried it on Linux and it worked for me.

I came across this solution in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3102501/2557681).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Alex's excellent investigation, it means that setting the flag from another thread would not cause the deadlock. The original code will work if the interrupt method is changed as such:

```
from threading import Thread

(...)
    @staticmethod
    def interrupt():
        Thread(target=Class1._stop_event.set).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in Issue [#85772](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85772):

> I just spent a lot of time with this problem. I have a
> multiprocessing.Event that sleeps the MainThread of a child process
> and an interrupt handler that sets that event. As described here, when
> the interrupt triggers the event, the process hangs. Doing some
> research on the web, including on the cited stackoverflow topic, I got
> the following solution:
>
> Solutions for Linux with fork start method:
>
> 1. In the interrupt handler, call `threading.Thread(target=exit_event.set).start()`
> 2. Change multiprocessing.Event to threading.Event
>
> Solution for Linux with spawn start method
>
> 1. In the interrupt handler, call `threading.Thread(target=exit_event.set).start()`
>
> Windows:
>
> 1. Instead of using signal.signal() to change the interrupt handler, the solution was to use:
>
>    `import win32api`
>
>    `win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, add)`
>
> Reference:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler
>
> This works like a charm. The key difference is that it runs the
> interrupt funcition on a thread (named Dummy-1).
>
> 2. (Not a great solution) In the interrupt handler, call `threading.Thread(target=exit_event.set).start()`
>
>    - This solves the hang issue, but raises an InterruptedError exception